# What is the exact role of "AspNet_SqlCacheTablesForChangeNotification"

Tags: azure-sql-database, sqlcachedependency

We have a .NET 4.5 Azure Webrole with Azure (colocated) Caching enabled. We use Entity Framework 5.0 talking to an Azure SQL database.

We did some cleanup on our staging/testing and I noticed that the entity framework edmx file complains that

`Entity type 'AspNet_SqlCacheTablesForChangeNotification' is not mapped.`

We had also briefly experimented with SQL Sync. We don't know if it's SQL Sync or Azure caching that added that table (and any other elements?) to our database

What installs and uses `AspNet_SqlCacheTablesForChangeNotification`? Is it safe to remove it? Finally, any extra items that ride along with that table that we should cleanup?

Answer (score 1):

See [this article on MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/data-access/caching-data/using-sql-cache-dependencies-cs) on setting up SQL Server Cache Dependency.

This is set up using the `aspnet_regsql.exe` tool that comes with .Net

You can disable this using `aspnet_regsql -S localhost -U sa -P wrox -d Northwind -dd` however I am not sure if this removes the associated configuration tables (Worth a shot).  The tool may not work with `SQL Azure` in which case you may have to manually remove the table.

It's worth checking your `web.config` is not set up to expect Cache Dependencies by checking for this:

```
<system.web>
  <caching>
     <sqlCacheDependency enabled="true">
        <databases>
           <add name="Northwind" connectionStringName="AppConnectionString1" 
            pollTime="500" />
        </databases>
     </sqlCacheDependency>
  </caching>
</system.web>
```

Comment: Attached link is invalid.

Comment: Thank you for the heads up @AmirhosseinYari, fixed to point to MSDN